# require.js error (topojson not loading)

Tags: javascript, requirejs, topojson

Can anyone help me understand/fix this error?

Uncaught ReferenceError: topojson is not defined

I am new to requireJS and don't fully understand it.

Thank you in advance!

```js
require.config({
  paths: {
   d3: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min",
   geo: "//d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min",
   topo: "//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min"
 },
 shim: {
  geo: {
   deps: ["d3"]
  },
  topo:{
   deps: ["d3","geo"]
  }
 }

 
});

require(["d3","geo","topo"],function(){
 $(document).ready(RecruitingData.ondomready);
 $(document).bind('framework.resize',RecruitingData.scalescharts());
 $(document).bind('framework.resize',RecruitingData.scalescharts1()); 
 $(document).bind('framework.resize',RecruitingData.linechart()); 
 $(document).bind('framework.resize',RecruitingData.mapchart()); 
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about `require.js` but looking at the api, you are missing the arguments to your `require` callback:

```
require(["d3","geo","topo"],function(d3,geo,topojson){
    // you can now use topojson!
});
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a9jvmpjb/1/).