# How do I make all my graphs show up on my html page?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, layout

I am arranging 4 graphs on one html page using d3.js. The problem is that though all my graphs in someway show up, they don't interact like they should be doing or they overlap the axis (like the line graph and bar graph). In terms of the sunburst graph, it disappeared when I click on it. Is it an svg naming error?

```
<div>
  <svg width="800" height="500" id="line-chart"></svg>
  <svg width="500" height="400" id="map-chart"></svg>
</div>
<div>
  <svg width="900" height="400" id="bar-chart"></svg>
  <svg width="500" height="500" id="sunburst-chart"></svg>
</div>
```

I set up my page like that and then named each chart: svg, svg2, svg3, svg4– and then referred to the svg ID above (#line-chart). Not sure if that the right way get it done.

The expected results should be that all graphs are in a quadrant and are individually interactive. Also the map should show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use flexbox to add the spacing you desire. Based on your code snippets, you have no CSS to tell then graphs where to actually go, so they just appear with default settings.

Try this, it worked for me to make them into a grid.

```
.flexOnIt {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
}

</style>
<body>
<div class="flexOnIt">
     <svg width="800" height="500" id="line-chart"></svg>
     <svg width="500" height="400" id="map-chart"></svg>
</div>

<div class="flexOnIt">
     <svg width="900" height="400" id="bar-chart"></svg>
     <svg width="500" height="500" id="sunburst-chart"></svg>
</div>
```

Here is the error I am receiving (refer to comments for why this is being posted here)

[image: Error Codes]

Comment: I went to your link and edited this. Your elements weren't in a grid.

Comment: Ah thank you, would you happen to know why the map does no show up or why the axis for the line graph and bar chart are weirdly overlapping?

Comment: I know nothing about d3 js, but you may want to see if the map has a minimum size to be able to display. I'll try to look into it more

Comment: Where is the map-chart ID coming from? Which file in D3?

Comment: it is a json, so the script is http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js and the json code is https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4090846/raw/us.json. The graph works fine by itself but when I add it to my html page it does not show.

Comment: Another suggestion, use the link tag to seperate some of these large scripts/your css into files rather than having 1 huge file.

Comment: could that be causing the problem?

Comment: I doubt it, but it will be easier to debug by having more small files that do specific things rather than 1 large file that does everything

Comment: what does the link tag look like?

Comment: I would suggest splitting the file into each time you call a new <script> and then adding comments at the top of the file as to what each is doing

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css"> for your css. Then add <script src="file path or url"></script> for the scripts

Comment: ok will do thanks! if you can solve why the map isn't showing up please let me know!

Comment: Are there any errors showing in the developer tools in your browser (CTRL + SHIFT + I in chrome)?

Comment: yes, Uncaught ReferenceError: topojson is not defined
    at (index):478
    at Object.<anonymous> (d3.v3.min.js:1)
    at Object.t (d3.v3.min.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.i (d3.v3.min.js:1)

Comment: I would guess that's a missing dependency.

Comment: what does that mean? and how was I fix that?

Comment: there could be a missing script or one isnt linked. if could also be a typo in your topoJson. Find where that is created and let me know what you find

Comment: its says line 478 in my plunkr code but the script is defined above. why is it not reading it?

Comment: Check out this link, could be helpful      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770061/require-js-error-topojson-not-loading

Comment: From what I've gathered it could be an issue with the order things are called so it things it is missing a dependancy

Comment: what do you suggest I do to fix that?

Comment: I would suggest looking into the other error that "Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "[object SVGPathE…"." There is an n given rather than m which seems like a typo somehwere

Comment: I would accept the answer then start a new question asking about the error. That is the only error and it happens every time it is called

Comment: I corrected the error that topojson wasn't being read. The browser wouldnt accept an http, had to be https. So as about this: "Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "[object SVGPathE…".

Comment: how did you find that error? like where is it located?

Comment: Developer tools in Chrome. Will add screenshot to answer

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197313/discussion-on-answer-by-yeet-how-do-i-make-all-my-graphs-show-up-on-my-html-page).